# C# Localization Shortcuts

Tags: c#

I don´t know how i should explain what i want to do.

In my Project are basicly 3 Sub-Projects.

- First Project: Holds all Properties and Localizations.
- Second Project is an Console Project, using the Properties from the First Project and some Localized Strings.
- Third Project is an Windows Forms Project, using all Properties and Localized Strings from the First Project.

The Localization is working without trouble, i can start both Projects and when i change the Culture, it changes the Strings.

But: I have to Write the whole Path to the String everywhere. 
Example:

```
Label.Text = Config.Localization.MyString
```

With the Settings, i can use an "Shortcut" by setting it to an new variable:

```
private Settings settings = Config.Properties.Settings.Default;
```

But with the Localization i cant to that to shorten it up.
Try´d the following:

```
    private Type locals = CodepackConfig.Localization;
    Label.Text = locals.MyString
```

Does somebody have hint for me how i can set a Variable to "Config.Localization"? And yes, i just code C# for 1 Month now, looks like a stupidly easy error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `using` directive's documentation.

I assume you're interested in something like

```
using Localization = Config.Properties.Localization;
```

1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution. Told you it was stupidly simple :D